# Is Forms Authentication Ticket Decryption possible with PHP?

Tags: c#, .net, php, authentication, encryption

I'm a PHP developer who knows almost nothing about .NET. I've been asked by the .NET guys at work to translate .NET code that decrypts an authentication ticket into PHP so that the PHP code can then set the appropriate session variables for my application to run. Is this even possible? I'm staring at the code and it's baffling me. I'll keep trying if someone can tell me it's not a waste of time for some reason I don't even know.  Thanks for any help!

Additional info: Can I even grab the ticket with PHP in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gumbo said, you need to take into account the algorithms involved. The asp.net authentication ticket uses:

1. Create a serialized forms
   authentication ticket. A byte array
   representation of the ticket is
   created.
2. Sign the forms authentication
   ticket. The message authentication
   code (MAC) value for the byte array
   is computed by using the algorithm
   and key specified by the validation
   and validationKey attributes of the
   machineKey element. By default, the
   SHA1 algorithm is used.
3. Encrypt forms authentication ticket.
   The second byte array that has been
   created is encrypted by using the
   Encrypt method of the
   FormsAuthentication class. The
   Encrypt method internally uses the
   algorithm and key specified by the
   decryption and decryptionKey
   attributes on the machineKey
   element. ASP.NET version 1.1 uses
   the 3DES algorithm by default.
   ASP.NET version 2.0 uses the
   Rinjdael (AES) algorithm by default.

Answer (score 5):

First off, open your machine.config and add in a machinekey entry. Set the decryption key and validation key according to a randomly generated ones from a machinekey generator for aspnet 2.0.

Be sure to use the default's, ie. AES and SHA1.
Now that you have the AES decrypt key, store it somewhere because you are going to need it on the php side. 
In your dot net app, go into the web.config and get the forms auth cookie name, usually something like .ASPXAUTH

Now go to the PHP side. Download and set up an AES encryption library, like this one, http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/

Then in PHP you can do something like this (this uses the phpsec lib):

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Crypt/AES.php');

$authCookie = $_COOKIE['_ASPXAUTH'];

echo $authCookie;

$aes = new Crypt_AES();

$aes->setKey('BCDCBE123654F3E365C24E0498346EB95226A307857B9BDE8EBA6198ACF7F03C');

echo $aes->decrypt($authCookie);
```

Now what ends up coming out is going to first be pm + the SHA1 hash + a byte representation of the auth ticket. You must convert the serialized bytes to a string to make it readable. Can someone else iluminate on that last step?

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443)

> The forms authentication ticket is
>   used to tell the ASP.NET application
>   who you are. Thus, ticket is building
>   block of Forms Authentication's
>   security.
>
> The ticket is encrypted and signed
>   using the  configuration
>   element of the server's Machine.config
>   file. ASP.NET 2.0 uses the
>   decryptionKey and the new decryption
>   attribute of the  element
>   to encrypt forms authentication
>   tickets. The decryption attribute lets
>   you specify the encryption algorithm
>   to use. ASP.NET 1.1 and 1.0 use 3DES
>   encryption, which is not configurable.
>   Tampering with the ticket value is
>   determined by a failure to decrypt the
>   ticket on the server. As a result, the
>   user will be redirected to the logon
>   page.
>
> If the application is deployed in a
>   Web farm, you must make sure that the
>   configuration files on each server
>   share the same value for the
>   validationKey and decryptionKey
>   attributes in the  tag,
>   which are used for hashing and
>   decryption of the ticket respectively.
>   You must do this because you cannot
>   guarantee which server will handle
>   successive requests. For more
>   information about
>   FormsAuthenticationTicket encryption
>   and Web farm deployment
>   considerations, visit the following
>   MSDN Web site:

So, you can specify what encryption/decryption algorithm to follow and the key. You can use the same decryption logic in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the decryption algorithm you sure can implement it in PHP.