# Decrypt asp.net authentication cookie manually

Tags: asp.net, node.js, cookies, form-authentication

I am implementing chat server on node js as integrating to my aps.net application.

My users are authenticated to aps.net application and authentication cookie is generated with machine key. Somehow I need to get this authentication cookie send to nodejs chat server and check if cookie is valid.

So far I tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34882672/492258) but no progress. There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988018/492258) for PHP developers.

Inside .net application it is as easy as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220843/492258).

However, now I am trying to do in nodejs application with [edgejs](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge), running .net codes inside nodejs

How can I manually decrypt authentication cookie with .net (outside of that web application)?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @ChristopheGigax I answered [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34882672/5128464) -- might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks ! I endend up by another way than decrypting the cookie.

Comment: @ChristopheGigax I would be interested to know what you did, would it be appropriate as an answer to this question or could you ask another question that covers it and then post the answer.

Comment: Not really an answer, but we used the Claim mechanism of ASP.NET Core Identity to pass data we needed. No decryption anymore.